# "svn: Path ' ' is not a directory" when trying to localize

Tags: xcode, svn, localization

I am working with Xcode 4.5.2.

My project is under svn version. Previously I localizes my application for Japanese through Xcode interface (click on xib, png ..., then in inspector view click on "make localized"). This automatically moved the file in jp.lproj folder and the svn was totally fine with this.

Then I manually add en.lproj folders next to each jp.lproj and moved the english version of each file in it. From the project setting Info panel, I clicked on localize, and chose English. A dialog box ask me which japanese version file I want to localize, but after clicking on "finish", xCode keep showing the message : "svn:Path '/User/.......MyXcodeProject/.../en.proj/...png is not a directory". I don't have this message if I don't manually create the folder and copy the file in it. Instead XCode automatically create the folder en.lproj, copy the japanese version in it and do the necessary svn modification.

Is there a mean to avoid this message and force xCode to use the already existing english version ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have unknowingly copied the

> .svn

file when you did the copy. You should remove this file and "Add" and check in it should work then